# I can not print correctly a figure of ics

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, for-loop, move, helper

I'm doing an exercise in c # where I have to move a character within a rectangle. The problem is that the frame right sfasa (see photo). I do not find the mistake someone can help me?

Main Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ricorsione2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           World mappa = new World(10,30,4,4);//grande 10X10 parte indice y,x
           char cho;
           do
           {


               Console.Clear();
               mappa.print();
               Console.WriteLine("\n\nDove vuoi andare?");
               cho = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
               mappa.choose(cho);
              
           
           }

           while (true);
           Console.ReadLine();

        }

    
            


        }

        
    }
```

World CLass:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ricorsione2
{
    class World
    {

        
        int myLung;
        int myAltezza;
        int myX;
        int myY;
        public int startX;
        public int startY;


        public World(int lungArray, int altezzaArray, int xStartded, int yStarted)
        {
            this.myLung = lungArray;
            this.myAltezza = altezzaArray;
            this.myX = xStartded;
            this.myY = yStarted;
            startX = myX;
            startY = myY;
            

        }

        public void choose(char pos)
        {
            
                    switch(pos)
                    {

                        case'r':
                            move(1, 0); //x,y
                            break;

                        case'l':
                            move(-1, 0);
                            break;

                        case'u':
                            move(0, -1);
                           
                            break;

                        case'd':
                            move(0, 1); 
                            break;

                    }


        }



        public void move(int horizontal, int vertical)
        {
                    myX = (myX + vertical);
                    myY = (myY + horizontal);
        }
           
        
        
        public void print()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<=myLung;i++)
            {
                Console.Write('\n');
                for(int j=0; j<=myAltezza; j++)
                {
                    if (i == myX && j == myY)

                        Console.Write('.');

                    if ((i == 0 || i == myLung) || (j == 0 || j == myAltezza))
                    

                        Console.Write('*');
                         
                    else

                        Console.Write(" ");

                   
                   
                    

                   
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found it, when you print the the dot `.` then your code continues, you should go to next `i` using `continue;`:

change your code to:

```
if (i == myX && j == myY)
{
    Console.Write('.');
    continue;
}
```

[More Read Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you should add `else` statement into your `if` statement:

```
    if (i == myX && j == myY)
        Console.Write('.');
    else if ((i == 0 || i == myLung) || (j == 0 || j == myAltezza))
        Console.Write('*');
    else
        Console.Write(" ");
```